# Transiesta Electrode Run

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am using a (1,1,1) gold electrode for electron transport experiments using Transiesta. I have never used it before. I am wondering if when I do the electrode run, do I build a system where it is the left and right electrodes connected to each other? or do I use the entire device (molecule AND electrodes) and just set a flag in the file?

(In response to andselisk's request for more information about Transiesta: it is a computational chemistry program that is a part of the Siesta Suite. It is used mainly for electron transport calculations.)

Comment: It looks like spam...

Comment: @Mithoron Actually I asked OP to provide a description of what *Transiesta* is (I'm that illiterate, yep:) ), if this is what made you think so. I don't think this is spam, more on a par with other software-related (e.g. Gaussian) questions, I believe.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @andselisk - see https://departments.icmab.es/leem/siesta/.

Comment: I don't see any evidence for this being spam - @Mithoron, you can retract your flag if you change your mind.

Comment: How is this spam???? I do undergrad research in computational chemistry and molecular mechanics. I use software that sometimes has a lack of documentation. Some of the programs I use are Gabedit, Jmol, Gaussian, and now siesta. I am extremely confused as to how this question could be deemed as spam???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a pro myself, and am still experimenting/learning about SIESTA and TranSIESTA. What me and my colleagues usually do is run the electrode files, i.e., the left, then the right, then the device (which includes both the left and the right electrodes).

In response to your question, your electrodes should be part of your device, but in their respective .fdf files, they should have lattice parameters such that the electrodes are periodic and semi-infinite. Then in the main device, the left electrode coordinates should be listed first, followed by the device, then the right electrode. The electrodes need not be directly connected (I don't think you should, but then again, I've never tried that).

An example might help.

Say I have a rectangular sheet of atoms arranged in a $m$ by $n$ grid = $mn$ number of atoms (in the $x$ and $y$ direction respectively), and a unit cell of this sheet is $p$ by $q$, where $p$ = $m$ and $q$ = $n$/10. And the transport direction in this case is the $y$ direction (in the manual it must *always* be in the $z$ direction, but for the sake of simplicity we use $y$ here).

For an electrode of 3 unit cells (you can have any number, but the manual suggests at least 3 last I remembered), my left electrode .fdf file would include the coordinates of the first $p$ times 3$q$ atoms, with the lattice parameter block containing a cell size that would ensure the 3 unit cell electrode is periodic (so that it's semi-infinite to the side not connected to the device). I do the same for the the right electrode file, but this time with the last $p$ times 3$q$ atoms.

Moving on to the device, the .fdf file would have coordinates of all $xy$ atoms, arranged in the order of left ($y$ = 0 to 3$q$), middle (non-electrode, so coordinates of $y$ =
 3$q$ to $m$-3$q$), and the right ($y$ = $m$-3$q$ to $m$). The lattice parameter in this full device file doesn't quite matter as the electrodes I don't think, and typically I use a huge box so that there are no effects from periodic boundary conditions.

And that's how I usually do it. You can play around with the parameters and flags as well to suit your computation needs. After TranSIESTA I run tbtrans (which is a post-processor they provided), but I'm getting weird computation times with that. Also, this is SIESTA 4.0 I'm using, so double check the manual if your version is different.

Feel free to comment or provide suggestions on my methods, as I would appreciate if I could get more insight on how to use the software.

Comment: Ok so there are no specific flags that need to be put in the FDF when I am running transiesta on the unit cell for the electrode? I am using a 1,1,1 gold molecule as it is the most stable crystalline structure. I am using 3-7-3-7 as the unit cell. So that is what I put in the calculation for the electrode, but is there any thing i need to add so that it knows its a electrode? Or just when I do the entire scattered region the unit cell output goes in where the right and left electrodes are?

Comment: Not on the electrodes no. By executing TranSIESTA on the left and right .fdf files you'll get .TSHS files, which you then specify in your scattering region .fdf file where it can find the left and right electrode .TSHS files. The only place you need to 'tell' TranSIESTA the electrodes would be the scattering region .fdf file - that is, you set the paths to your left and right electrodes in that scat. region file.

Maybe go through the examples that in your SIESTA folder (they come with the compilation), and maybe some internet examples as well. You'll understand better with familiarity.

Answer (score 5):

There is a manual available that [states](https://departments.icmab.es/leem/siesta/Documentation/Manuals/siesta-4.0.pdf) (page 111).

> TranSiesta
>   defines the Left Electrode to be the first atoms specified in the SR
>   .fdf
>   file,
>   and the Right Electrode to be the last ones.  The transport direction has to be considered
>   to be the the third cartesian axis, the
>   z
>   axis.  The Left Electrode atoms must have smaller
>   z
>   components than the Right Electrode atoms.  It is also crucial that the atomic positions
>   specified at the left (right) EL calculation must be equivalent to the left (right) electrode
>   part of the SR setup.  Here, equivalent means that they can be made equal by a simple
>   translation  in  space.   It  is  also  possible  to  use  buffer  atoms.

There is more information that I think may address further doubts in the manual as well. I am not very familiar with the program. So, this is as much as I can help you. You could try asking the mailing list, though SIESTA's mailing list does not get many responses to be honest.